# ¿Cuál es el error del Método que tengo?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Entidades;
using System.IO;

namespace VENTANA
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void juegoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string nombreJuego = txtNombreJuego.Text;
            string genero = comboGenero.Text;
            DateTime fechaLanzamiento = dtpFechaLanzamiento.Value;

            Juego juegoARegistrar = new Juego(nombreJuego, genero, fechaLanzamiento);
            if (juegoARegistrar.Guardar() == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Éxito al guardar", "Guardar en Disco", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error al guardar", "Guardar en Disco", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void horafecha_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void lblhora_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void lblhf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void salir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

======================================================

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace Entidades
{
    public class Juego
    {
        private string NombreJuego;
        private string Genero;
        private DateTime FechaPublicacion;

        public Juego()
        {

        }
        public Juego(string nombreJuego, string genero, DateTime fechaPublicacion)
        {
            NombreJuego = nombreJuego;
            Genero = genero;
            FechaPublicacion = fechaPublicacion;
        }

        public string ObtenerNombreJuego()
        {
            return NombreJuego;
        }

        public void AsignarNombreJuego(string nombreJuego)
        {
            NombreJuego = nombreJuego;
        }

        public string ObtenerGenero()
        {
            return Genero;
        }
        public void AsignarGenero(string genero)
        {
            Genero = genero;
        }
        public DateTime ObtenerFechaPublicacion()
        {
            return FechaPublicacion;
        }
        public void AsignarFechaPublicacion(DateTime fechaPublicacion)
        {
            FechaPublicacion = fechaPublicacion;
        }

        public bool Guardar()
        {
            bool exitoAlGuardar = true;
            try
            {
                StreamWriter escritor = File.AppendText("ListaJuego.txt");
                escritor.Write(NombreJuego);
                escritor.Write(";" + Genero);

//ERROR
                    ***escritor.Write(";" + FechaPublicacion.ToShortDateString());***

//ERROR

////////////////////////////////////////////
                    escritor.WriteLine();
////////////////////////////////////////////
//ERROR
                    ***escritor.Close();***
//ERROR
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                exitoAlGuardar = false;
            }
            return exitoAlGuardar;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un error a la hora de compilar, en el segundo código en las lineas `//ERROR//` (Ver segundo texto), me subraya como si no estuviera declarado el método, pero ya lo tengo declarado en el primer texto.
Mi pregunta es.

¿Cómo puedo declarar bien o cual es el problema qué tengo?

> Gravedad  Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido
>   Error CS1061  "DateTime" no contiene una definición para
>   "ToShortDateString" ni se encuentra ningún método de extensión
>   "ToShortDateString" accesible que acepte un primer argumento del tipo
>   "DateTime" (¿falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de
>   ensamblado?)
>
> Gravedad  Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido
>   Error CS1061  "StreamWriter" no contiene una definición para "Close" ni
>   se encuentra ningún método de extensión "Close" accesible que acepte
>   un primer argumento del tipo "StreamWriter" (¿falta alguna directiva
>   using o una referencia de ensamblado?)

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Los errores deben estar copiados en la pregunta, ya que las imagenes son dificiles de leer.

Comment: La clase esta bien, y el metodo tambien. tendras un error en algun otro lado?

Comment: Gracias por los ejemplos de las preguntas, Si, tengo entendido que posiblemente tenga error en otro codigo, en otro form, el siguiente;

Comment: Edité la publicación ahí está.

Comment: escritor.Write(";" + FechaPublicacion.value.ToShortDateString()); (No sirvió)

Comment: Por favor. Pon todos los errore sque estas recibiendo, como errores. Definitivamente el problema no esta donde vos pensas.

Comment: Revisa toda tu pregunta, el error no esta ahi!

Comment: Ya volví hacer toda la publicación, gracias

Comment: Por favor. otra vez te lo repito, los errores tienen que estar en la pregunta y no como imagen. y pone todos los errores que recibis

Comment: Ya lo coloqué en el texto

Comment: Que formato de fecha esta obteniendo `FechaPublicacion` ?

Comment: Que tipo de proyecto estás haciendo? Es posible que sea UWP o .net core? Prueba a cambiar `ToShortDateString` por `.ToString("d")`

Comment: si usas `DateTime.ToString()` en lugar de D`ateTime.ToShortDateString()` tenes el mismo error?